# Pandas - DataFrame Convert column or Pivoting Column into a new row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
EmpID   FirstName    LastName     Relationship   FirstName.1  LastName.1   Relationship.1
1        Ax            Bx              1A           Cx          Dx             1B
```

My excel source file didn't have .1 on the duplicate columns but pandas created it - when I read it, I think that's the way it is - you cant have duplicate columns in the database.

I want to convert this into a dataframe like this,

```
EmpID       FirstName          LastName       Relationship
 1           Ax                   Bx             1A
 1           Cx                   Dx             1B
```

How do we do this transformation. Thanks.

Comment: Would that be an idea to create dataframes with 4 columns only: EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Relationship, ...and then merge the dataframes with `pd.merge` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two new dataframes, and then append the second to the first:

```
df1 = df[['EmpID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Relationship']]
df2 = df[['EmpID', 'FirstName.1', 'LastName.1', 'Relationship.1']]

df2.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('.1',''), inplace=True)

df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

```
>>> print(df)

0 EmpID FirstName LastName Relationship
0     1        Ax       Bx           1A
1     1        Cx       Dx           1B
```

Comment: Thank you. never even thought about breaking it like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `pandas.wide_to_long`, but your column names aren't perfect, so we make the first instances stubs by appending `.0` to the name.

```
import pandas as pd
df.columns = [f'{x}.0' if not '.' in x and x != 'EmpID' else x for x in df.columns]

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Relationship'], 
                sep='.', i='EmpID', j='suff').reset_index().drop(columns='suff')

   EmpID FirstName LastName Relationship
0      1        Ax       Bx           1A
1      1        Cx       Dx           1B
```